# Wordpress dynamic sidebar not work

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

Hi everyone i am developing a theme for wordpress i read a lot for dynamic sidebar but they aren't work my function code :

```
<?php 
if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        'before_widget' => '<div class="wcon">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
?>
```

and my sidebar.php code :

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and i am geting sidebar.php using this code :

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

It seems be fine but i can't add widget to it no link in wordpress panel and no direct access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your functions.php

add this below

```
//initialize addiional sidebars.
    if(function_exists('register_sidebar')){
        register_sidebar(
            array(
                'name' => 'second-sidebar' ,
                'id' => 'second-sidebar',
                'before_widget' => '<li class ="widget-container>"',
                'after_widget' => '</li>',
                'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
                'after_title' => '</h3>'
            )
        );}
```

then where ever you want it to appear, add this

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('second-sidebar'); ?>
```

Then go to your wordpress backend, in the widgets area, youll see a "second-sidebar" tab on the right hand side. Drop in your widgets and you should be good to go.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

functions.php

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_register_sidebars' );

function my_register_sidebars() {

register_sidebar(
    array(
        'id' => 'primary',
        'name' => __( 'Primary' ),
        'description' => __( 'Main Sidebar' ),
                    'before_widget' => '<div class="wcon">',
                    'after_widget' => '</div>',
                    'before_title' => '<h3>',
                    'after_title' => '</h3>'
    )
);
}
```

sidebar.php

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('primary'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler answer:

//sidebar php file

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-name') ) : ?>
  <p>You're not using a dynamic sidebar</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

//functions.php

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
  register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=>'sidebar-name',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="your-class">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2>', //h3, h4, h5, whatever size header you prefer
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
  ));
```